# "Performative" meaning "in name only"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Recently I'm seeing the word "performative" being used with the meaning "in name only". I'm seeing it only on Reddit, so it could be a local phenomenon.

Examples:

- *[The separate measure for sick leave was performative so they could say “look, we tried!”](https://old.reddit.com/r/LateStageCapitalism/comments/ze2u7g/aoc_becomes_the_first_prounion_female_latina/iz4nvlw/)*
- *[performative "apologies"](https://www.reddit.com/r/BestofRedditorUpdates/comments/z7zfgq/oop_doesnt_stop_his_daughter_dating_his_sons_bully/iy9q7l5/)*
- *[OOP is a performative parent](https://www.reddit.com/r/BestofRedditorUpdates/comments/z7zfgq/oop_doesnt_stop_his_daughter_dating_his_sons_bully/iy93fvc/)*

And if you search for 'performative site:reddit.com', it's pages and pages of it used in that sense.

Is that a generally accepted usage?

Comment: "made or done for show", [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/performative). Reddit is a wonderful place but you should do some research elsewhere too.

Comment: In name only, for show, and by virtue of its utterance ... all say the same thing. (Links 2 and 3 go to different URLs, but the same quotes.)

Comment: Merriam-Webster seems to be the only online dictionary with that definition. Maybe they jumped the gun? Or being in M-W does make a definition "official"?

Comment: Those are different things. Links 2 and 3 go to different quotes.

Comment: Wiktionary has this sense too. It is usually the first to 'allow in' new senses. OED is often seen as the true register of wordness, but by the editors' own admission shouldn't be. _But M-W etc have rigorous testing procedures._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That of sense of *performative* is common in academia. And here it is in the OED:

> **performative**, *adj.* and *n.*
> **2.** Usually *depreciative.* Of action, speech, behaviour, etc.: done or expressed for the sake of appearance, esp. to impress others
> or to improve one's own image (typically with the implication of
> insincere intent or superficial impact).
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford
> English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

The first of three attestations is at 1996:

> <sub>1996   C. Kaplan *Erotics of Talk* 162      If we are
> to provide more than merely performative or poetic justice we need
> clearer blueprints for meaningful social action.</sub>
>
> <sub>2014   @isanaka 30 Oct. in *twitter.com* (accessed 30 June
> 2022)       When a dude says ‘i'm not perfect’ with performative
> humility I wanna be like ‘yeah, man, literally no one has ever assumed
> that.’</sub>
>
> <sub>2022   *Edmonton* (Alberta) *Sun* (Nexis) 4 May a11    
> These small sacrifices, despite their good intentions, are ultimately
> performative measures meant to show other cities and countries how
> adept we are at fighting climate change.</sub>

Comment: As a qualification of the first sentence of this answer, it should be noted that those who work in the parts of the academia devoted to linguistics and philosophy are likely, upon hearing that word, to first think of the entirely different sense that it has as a technical term in these disciplines.